# Conda fails to build on Julia 1.0

Tags: build, julia, conda

Trying to add and build Conda results in the following error:

[image: Conda fails to build in Julia 1.0.]

Does anybody know what the cause of this is?

Comment: It looks like `Conda.jl` is still not ready for 1.0, for now, v0.7 is a better choice for getting started. It's better to post this question on `Conda.jl`'s Github issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch seems to build correctly:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Conda#master
(v1.0) pkg> build Conda
```